# Add a Pandas dataframe beside an existing dataframe of the same size, i.e. on the next column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was playing around with data using pandas dataframe and bumped into this problem.

Is it possible to copy an existing dataframe and add the copy to next column of that particular dataframe?

I was able to do so if the dataframe have only one column of data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(6*['a'])
copy = df.copy()
df.insert(len(df), len(df), copy)
print(df)
```

Which gave this

```
   0  6
0  p  p
1  p  p
2  p  p
3  p  p
4  p  p
5  p  p
```

But if I were to try inserting a dataframe with more than one column

```
df.insert(2, len(df), copy)
print(df)
```

which definitely gave an error since the insert function apparently supports adding one column at a time, I guess.

```
raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {item}, already exists")
ValueError: cannot insert 6, already exists
```

So, can anyone please give some suggestion on how to add a dataframe with more than one columns to another dataframe.

And should I be using numpy for this? I'm not quite familiar with numpy.

EDIT
Would like to clarify things.

My original dataframe is this

```
   0  1
0  p  p
1  p  p
2  p  p
3  p  p
4  p  p
5  p  p
```

So, is there a way to copy the original dataframe and add it to the next column.

Expected output would be like this

```
  0  1  2  3
0  p  p  p  p
1  p  p  p  p
2  p  p  p  p
3  p  p  p  p
4  p  p  p  p
5  p  p  p  p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insert` only allows to insert one column at a time. If you want to insert 2 columns, you can use the `concat` method of pandas, passing the previous data frame and the new one, and setting the `axis=1` so it is added as columns and not rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(6*['p'])
copy = df.copy()
df.insert(len(df.columns), len(df.columns), copy)
print(df)
copy = df.copy()
df = pd.concat([df, copy], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Didn't work. Got this error ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1. The copy I'm inserting has two columns by the way.

Comment: Just edited the answer, this is following your code, this is what you're trying to do.  If you expect a different output, please edit and post the expected output.

Comment: I've edited my question. Can you have a look at it again?

Comment: Looked at it and think I got the idea of what you mean. Look at the edit again please.

Comment: One last question. How can I change the label of the columns so it becomes 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and not 0, 1, 0, 1, which looks strange

Comment: just add this line of code at the end. `df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(0, len(df.columns)) `